# reading .wav file: converting little endian and big endian to integer

Tags: math, hex, wav

I'm writing a little program to read a .wav file. According to the wav specs I've been looking at:

[image: graphic of .wav file format]

it looks like the second four bytes are a 4 byte little endian number. I think this means that the least significant byte is the first one, byte number 5, so in otherwords, I read them from left to right. From what I've been reading, I think I should multiply them like this:

```
n=bytearray[5]+(bytearray[6]*256)+(bytearray[7]*256)+(bytearray[8]*16777216)
```

so byte in

but that comes out to a pretty damn large number, 1,459,618,138 in decimal for a file that is only 90k long. So I think I'm making a mistake here somewhere.

for the other numbers, if I understand the difference between little endian and big endian is right to left vs left to right order of the bytes?

Comment: You're processing the wrong 4 bytes - it should be 4..7, not 5..8

Comment: I'm interested too!, but I need to know how the header is changed... I see that is RIFF to RIFX, but is only this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array is indexed from 0, so the bytes you want are 4, 5, 6 and 7:

```
n=bytearray[4]+(bytearray[5]*256)+(bytearray[6]*65536)+(bytearray[7]*16777216)
```

(Note that your third multiplier needs to be `65536`, not `256`.)